# Facebook group post scheduling

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am developing a website that uses Facebook's API (Javascript) and one of the requirements was to be able to publish / schedule posts to pages and groups that the user controls / is a member of. I have had no problem setting up the post scheduling for Pages, but I realized that the scheduling functionality is not available when it comes to groups.

I have seen desktop applications that claim to do so, but I suppose you have to give your Facebook account details and the application has to run in the background. Are there any workarounds to achieve group post scheduling via the API ?

Thanks in advance for any replies

Comment: No, and I think deliberately so. Scheduled posts are only available to pages, whereas real users are supposed to post in real-time. And since groups are for real users as well …

Comment: (And for an app to post in the background at a later time does of course not mean you have to give them your login credentials – that is what access tokens are _for_, after all …)

Answer (score 0):

you definitely cannot post on groups with the facebook api, they don't allow that as a spam prevention, if you want to implement that yourself you will need to program it and not rely on their api, or you can use already made tools like http://www.massplanner.com/